# turn off sound alerts upon closing applications, emails, etc

Tags: audio

I did something in my settings that is causing a sound/alert every time I close, delete or clear something.  Looked through all my sound settings & not finding what I changed.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This way may help you locate the problem:

- Run *Control Panel > Sound*
- Position to the tab "Sounds"
- Scroll through the list :
  The actions that are assigned a sound have a "speaker" icon to their left
- You may listen to the assigned sound by selecting an item and clicking on the
  "Test" button
- Once you find the right item, click the drop-down list just under "Sounds:"
  and set it to "(None)" (this is the first in the list of sounds)
- When finished, click OK.